# Why is the code in this closure executed en bloc?

Tags: javascript

Consider this closure:

```
var getFunction = function(a, b, c) {
    return function () {
        console.log("A");

        foo(a, b, c); // takes a couple of seconds

        console.log("B");
    }
}
```

When I make use of it like this

```
var bar = getFunction(a, b, c);
bar();
```

it will output "A" and "B" at once after having done the calculations in foo - and not output "A", the wait for foo to finish, and then output "B".

Why is that?

Comment: Sidenote: In my application I am trying to set a wait cursor. I´m using "console.log" for simplicity in the example.

Comment: Do you mean `foo` runs *before* A and B appear in the console?

Comment: `foo` is probably async...

Comment: console.log "for simplicity" might be a bad example, because it is asynchronous in some aspects. What mechanism are you using exactly to read those values? Your issue might be that javascript is single-threaded, and *while* that long `foo` is executing, nothing can access the value of `A`.

Comment: I am using some jQuery `$("*").css("cursor", "progress");` and `$("*").css("cursor", "default");` instead of console.log - with the same result.

Comment: Note that in some browsers `console.log` will actually need a bit of free time to execute; if the event loop is bloated it won't show anything before it has the time to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that neither logging in the console nor styling elements block JS execution. That is, first the function will run completely, and then the console will show the queued items or the style of the elements will be updated.

```js
document.body.style.background = 'red';
var d = new Date();
while(new Date() - d < 1e3); // Wait 1 second
document.body.style.background = 'green';
```

For example, in the snippet above you don't see the red background, because the code does something like this:

- Add to queue: make background red as soon as possible
- Do useless operations
- Add to queue: make background green as soon as possible
- Now there is no code running, so queued operations can be done

  - Make the background red
  - Immediately after the above, make the background green

Instead, you may want something like

- Make background red as soon as possible
- Once the background is red, do some operations
- Once completed, make background green as soon as possible

In order to achieve that, you must split your code into different parts and delay them.

```js
document.body.style.background = 'red';
setTimeout(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  while(new Date() - d < 1e3); // Wait 1 second
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.style.background = 'green';
  }, 100);
}, 100);
```

Then, the browser will be able to take advantage of that delay to log things in the console or update the style of your elements.

Comment: Many thanks for the thourough explanation! Unfortunately my upvote does not qualify. My problem ist solved, though. Thanks.